# How to get a name of Column or change the name of existing?

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, distributed-computing, punctuation

I have a task to build a function "removePunctuation" that strips the punctuation and as result pass this test:

```
# TEST Capitalization and punctuation (4b)
testPunctDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(" The Elephant's 4 cats. ",)])
testPunctDF.show()
Test.assertEquals(testPunctDF.select(removePunctuation(col('_1'))).first()[0],
                  'the elephants 4 cats',
                  'incorrect definition for removePunctuation function')
```

This is what i managed to write.

```
def removePunctuation(column):
    """Removes punctuation, changes to lower case, and strips leading and trailing spaces.

    Note:
        Only spaces, letters, and numbers should be retained.  Other characters should should be
        eliminated (e.g. it's becomes its).  Leading and trailing spaces should be removed after
        punctuation is removed.

    Args:
        column (Column): A Column containing a sentence.

    Returns:
        Column: A Column named 'sentence' with clean-up operations applied.
    """

    return lower(trim(regexp_replace("column_name", "[\W_]+"," "))).alias("sentence");
```

But i still can not make function regexp_replace to use alias "sentence". I am getting this error:

> AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'sentence' given input columns:
>   [_1];"

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
stringWithPunctuation.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

which uses [c](/questions/tagged/c) under the hood, simply the best in terms of efficiency!

---

Your attempt:

```
return lower(trim(regexp_replace(, "[\W_]+"," "))).alias("sentence");
```

doesn't seem to use the parameter `column` anywhere, which may explain the error.

Comment: oh sorry, there is an error in the code i have posted, in regexp_replace() first argument must have bean "column_name", Anyway i have solved it already, but thanks.

Comment: @DmitrijKostyushko glad you solved it! Had I know your code in your question was not the one you were using, I might have been able to post a better question. Remember to accept the answer later. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly I was able just to pass column object in `regexp_replace()` args instead of column name.